# Far sighted mirror reflection

Tags: reflection

I am far sighted. I need reading glasses to see clearly up to a distance of approximately 14 inches. Why, when I look in a mirror is the frame around the glass blurry but my face crystal clear?

Comment: When your face looks clear are your eyes 7 inches or more from the mirror?

Answer (score 1):

First, realize that we are talking here about how the lens of your eye treats the rays of light reaching it from the outside world.

The lens of a farsighted person is not strong enough to focus the diverging light from a nearby object into a sharp focus on the retina.  Adding the focusing power of an additional lens brings these nearby objects into sharp focus.

When you look at the frame of your mirror, the rays of light coming from the details on the frame are too divergent to be brought to focus.

Similarly, the rays of light from any stray fingerprints, post-it notes, or dust on the mirror will fail to focus.

*But the rays of light from your face are entirely different.*

The rays of light from a point on your face travel, diverging as they go, to the mirror.  Then, they are all reflected and travel, continuing to diverge, in the reverse direction until they reach your eye.

Your eye knows nothing about mirrors. As far as your eyes are concerned, the diverging rays are coming from an object behind the mirror.

This virtual image is located behind the mirror, at a distance equal to the distance of your face in front of the mirror.

So, if your near point is 20 cm, and you hold the mirror 15 cm from your face, the frame and surface of the mirror, at 15 cm will be out of focus, while the image of your face, at (15 + 15) or 30 cm, will be in focus.

Some cars are replacing interior rear-view mirrors with rear facing cameras, and screens in place of the mirror.  But, if the mirror/screen is too close, the system will not work for far-sighted individuals...

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Because the eye's focusing distance of the frame is the distance from your eyes to the frame. The eye's focusing distance to objects reflected in the mirror is the distance from your eyes to the mirror plus the distance from the mirror to the object you are looking at in the mirror. So if you are looking at your eyes in a mirror that is 10 inches away from your eyes, you will be focusing on your eyes as if they were 20 inches away, yet you would still focus on the mirror frame at 10 inches away.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that might be the answer